# How to check that all public methods of a class are virtual

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, nservicebus

In .net project there are a lot of entities implemented in c#. The requirement of used library (nservicebus for saga entities) is that all access methods to be declared as public and virtual, otherwise it failes during the deploy process.

It's reasonable to check that an entity's access methods are virtual on unit testing stage, s.a. deploy could take a lot of time (before it would be discovered)

Does anyone knows a good way to check that all public methods in a class are declared virtual in an nunit test?

Comment: That sounds like a perfect candidate for an FxCop rule, rather than a unit-test :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use kind of the same test to verify, that game engine wrapper has all public method as virtual. It makes testing easier and can dramatically reduce feedback time. Such methods I place under special class `DesignTests`, where I test, for example, that conventions are not violated in my projects. There are complex things, that `FxCop` can't detect. You can see the code below:

```
[Test]
public void AllPublicMethodsInUnityFacade_ShouldBeVirtual()
{
    var allPublicMethods = 
        typeof(UnityFacade).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                       BindingFlags.Instance |
                                       BindingFlags.Public);

    Assert.IsTrue(allPublicMethods.All(method => method.IsVirtual),
                  string.Join(", ", allPublicMethods
                                        .Where(method => !method.IsVirtual)
                                        .Select(method => method.Name)) 
                                     + " is not virtual");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reflections, Luke.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isvirtual.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class MyClass 
{
    public void MyMethod() 
    {
    }
    public static void Main() 
    {
        MethodBase m = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod");
        Console.WriteLine("The IsFinal property value of MyMethod is {0}.", 
                          m.IsFinal);
        Console.WriteLine("The IsVirtual property value of MyMethod is {0}.",
                          m.IsVirtual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a tool like [Fody/Virtuosity](https://github.com/Fody/Virtuosity#readme) to do this job for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main() 
{
    MethodInfo[] methodInfos = 
        typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public 
                                   | BindingFlags.Instance 
                                   | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

    Console.WriteLine("The number of public methods is: {0}", 
                      methodInfos.Length);

    Int32 virtualCount = 0;

    foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
    {
        if (methodInfo.IsVirtual)
            ++virtualCount;
    }

    if (virtualCount == methods.Length)
        Console.WriteLine("All the methods are virtual!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Only {0}/{1} methods are virtual!", 
                          virtualCount, methods.Length);    
}
```